# PHP WordPress - exclude by category description

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my footer. There is parade of categories with most articles in. I need to exclude here categories with description that starts with "XXX".
So If some categories have description that starts with "XXX", it may don´t show here.

Is it possible please? Im newbie in PHP so I dont know if can I declare category discreption here.

```
<?php global $teo_options;?>
<footer role="contentinfo">

<?php if(isset($teo_options['enable_popular_companies']) && $teo_options['enable_popular_companies'] == 1) { ?>
        <div class="stripe-regular">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <h2><?php _e('Name', 'Couponize');?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="popular-companies flexslider">
                        <ul class="rr slides">
                            <?php
                            $args['hide_empty'] = 1;
                            $args['orderby'] = 'count';
                            $args['order'] = 'desc';
                            if(isset($teo_options['blog_category']) && $teo_options['blog_category'] != '')
                                $args['exclude'] = implode(",", $teo_options['blog_category']);
                            $categories = get_categories($args);
                            foreach($categories as $category) {
                                $image = get_option('taxonomy_' . $category->cat_ID);
                                $image = $image['custom_term_meta'];
                            ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id );?>" class="wrapper-5 small">
                                        <img src="<?php echo aq_resize($image, 130, 130, true); ?>" alt="<?php echo $category->name;?> coupons">
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible but you're just complicating your problem.

Why would you identify a category by a piece of text in the Description? 
Also, searching in the description as it's text could end to be a slow and unnecessary query, if you have a lot of categories.

To solve it, I recommend you take a look at the documentation about [Including & Excluding Categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories).

What I would do is to make sub-categories and either hide them manually or do a trick between the child and parent categories.